# WCF Rest service how to Access post JSON data with out parameters

Tags: .net, json, wcf, wcf-rest

I created restful wcf service which works great for get. Now iam building some post methods. The client posts me data to this service in JSON format. The service method will not have any parameters so i need to read the jsondata from the request made. I am unable to figure out how should i be able to retrieve the data made from the request.

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/SaveEmployee", RequestFormat =    WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

public bool SaveEmployee()
        {
            //Capture Employee Object Data here and perform save
            return true;
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class Employee
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int Id
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            [DataMember]
            public string Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you setup your method with the data contract type it will populate with the request body and de-serialize for you.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/SaveEmployee", RequestFormat =            WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public bool SaveEmployee(Employee sentEmployee)
    {
        //Capture Employee Object Data here and perform save
        return true;
    }
```

If you cannot do it that way you would have to pass the json data in a URL parameter and manually de-serialize the content.